Technical Name for Bamboo Leaf Plant
Can someone provide a technical name for this plant.  Sometimes called "bamboo leaf plant" and is often used for plating of sushi or for cutting leaf for decorations for sushi plate.  Rhizomes for root system, does not bloom flowers, and prefers shade.  Found in Southern California.  Grows to about 36 inches tall.  See attached photo.

Does it have any distinct smell?

Right, I'm almost certain that this is an Aspidistra plant - the growth habit is  practically the same, and your description of it being used for plating sushi mirrors some of the traditional Chinese and Japanese uses for the plant. As for the flowers, it's probably had quite a few - Aspidistras bear rather strange-looking purple-maroon flowers just above or partially buried in the soil.

Interesting……..
